# wrong labels are displaying while exporting csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to categorize years of residence into different categories. But after exporting csv, it is showing different label.

Below is the code that I have tried.

```
newspaper_churn['Year Of Residence'] =pd.cut(newspaper_churn['Year Of Residence'], bins=4, labels=np.arange(4), right=False)

bins = [1, 15, 30, 45, np.inf]
names = ['1-15', '16-30', '31-45', '46+']

newspaper_churn['Residence'] = pd.cut(newspaper_churn['Year Of Residence'], bins, labels=names)
```

In the output while exporting it's showing Jan-15 label instead of 1-15.

Comment: I think pandas working nice, only excel sometimes modify data, so try some csv editor like notepad++ or similar for check data in csv.

Comment: Check the data with data.head() where data is your imported Excel/CSV file. The left column will show your index